# How do I filter out null array elements from a group value in a mongo aggregate query?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

My aggregate $group is:

```
{
    $group: {
        _id: { ["$dayOfYear"]: "$TagDateCreated" },
        disqualified: {
            $addToSet: {
                $cond: {
                    if: { $in: [ "$TagId", [109,220,115,113,238] ]},
                    then: "$ContactId",
                    else: null
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Which gives me a unique set of contactId's as disqualified but I need the null values removed. I've tried omitting the else statement int he $cond and various $filters in the $project that either don't remove anything, remove everything, or error.

Comment: Would it make sense to move query criteria { $in: [ "$TagId", [109,220,115,113,238] ]} into $match stage before $group and use push in the group stage ?

Comment: No, this query has other items in it that would make this impossible - I kept them out of the question for simplicity sake. Thank you though!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can add next pipeline stage after `$group`:

```
{
    $addFields: {
        disqualified: {
            $filter: {
                input: "$disqualified",
                as: "d",
                cond: {
                    $ne: [ "$$d", null ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[$addFields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/index.html) will overwrite existing array and using [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/index.html) you can remove `null` value

Comment: Perfect! Thank you.